# Support Vector Machine in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification, svm, iris-recognition

I need some help. I got ***.mat Matlab** file after extract the features from 2D static image. The extraction process was used 2D Haar Wavelet in Matlab Apps.
The problems are:
 1. How I want to use the *.mat Matlab file as an input to the SVM program in Matlab?

Addition information: 
i. The image is the iris image.
ii. [Link for the screen capture image of the example output after the extraction process](http://%3Ca%20href='http://postimg.org/image/l8dfkbh5b/'%20target='_blank'%3E%3Cimg%20src='http://s11.postimg.org/l8dfkbh5b/stack.jpg'%20border='0'%20alt=%22stack%22%20/%3E%3C/a%3E)

2. Based on the image, what is suitable/relevant data to be used in SVM in order to classify the image into 2 classes such as class 1 = Healthy Iris or class 2 = unhealthy iris. Or maybe somebody already got the sample Matlab code that similar with this case study, hope you willing to share the code.

TQ in advanced for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why this does not work for you and what the expected results are. SO policy is against asking *how to do this* kind of tutorial questions, see the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)